# Find Active customers in past X days

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am facing some hard times, Need quick help. It would be great if someone could assist me.
Thanks a lot in advance:)

I have 2 tables.
1st table: daily_customer_snapshot: the daily snapshot of the customer which looks something as shown below.

| c_id | date | state | location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| b1 | 2020-12-01 | Active | OOW |
| b1 | 2020-12-02 | Active | OOW |
| b1 | 2020-12-03 | Active | OOW |
| b1 | 2020-12-04 | Active | OOW |
| b1 | 2020-12-05 | Active | OOW |
| b3 | 2020-12-06 | Active | OOW |
| b3 | 2020-12-07 | Active | OOW |
| b3 | 2020-12-08 | Active | OOW |
| b1 | 2020-12-09 | Decay | IW |
| b2 | 2020-12-15 | Active | OOW |

2nd table: customer_date_series: contains the date series from the day user became our customer.
Ex: refer image 2: user b1 became our customer on '2020-12-01' and user b3 became our customer on '2020-12-06'
and b2 became our customer on '2020-12-15'. I have generated the date series with customer_id to count at any given date how many customers we had.

| c_id | date |
| --- | --- |
| b1 | 2020-12-01 |
| b1 | 2020-12-02 |
| b1 | 2020-12-03 |
| b1 | 2020-12-04 |
| b1 | 2020-12-05 |
| b1 | 2020-12-06 |
| b1 | 2020-12-07 |
| b1 | 2020-12-08 |
| b1 | 2020-12-09 |
| b1 | 2020-12-10 |
| b1 | 2020-12-11 |
| b1 | 2020-12-12 |
| b1 | 2020-12-13 |
| b1 | 2020-12-14 |
| b1 | 2020-12-15 |
| b1 | 2020-12-16 |
| b3 | 2020-12-06 |
| b3 | 2020-12-07 |
| b3 | 2020-12-08 |
| b3 | 2020-12-09 |
| b3 | 2020-12-10 |
| b3 | 2020-12-11 |
| b3 | 2020-12-12 |
| b3 | 2020-12-13 |
| b3 | 2020-12-14 |
| b3 | 2020-12-15 |
| b3 | 2020-12-16 |
| b2 | 2020-12-15 |
| b2 | 2020-12-16 |

I left joined table1 (customer_date_series) with table2 (daily_customer_snapshot) to get the overview of the customer behavior at any given date.
I got the results as displayed in image 3.

Query to Join:

```
    select 
    bds.date,
    bds.c_id,
    b.state,
    b.location
    
FROM
    customer_date_series bds LEFT JOIN daily_customer_snapshot b ON bds.c_id = b.c_id and bds.date = b.date
ORDER BY
    1,2;
```

| date | c_id | state | location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-01 | b1 | Active | OOW |
| 2020-12-02 | b1 | Active | OOW |
| 2020-12-03 | b1 | Active | OOW |
| 2020-12-04 | b1 | Active | OOW |
| 2020-12-05 | b1 | Active | OOW |
| 2020-12-06 | b1 |  |  |
| 2020-12-06 | b3 | Active | OOW |
| 2020-12-07 | b1 |  |  |
| 2020-12-07 | b3 | Active | OOW |
| 2020-12-08 | b1 |  |  |
| 2020-12-08 | b3 | Active | OOW |
| 2020-12-09 | b1 | Decay | IW |
| 2020-12-09 | b3 |  |  |
| 2020-12-10 | b1 |  |  |
| 2020-12-10 | b3 |  |  |
| 2020-12-11 | b1 |  |  |
| 2020-12-11 | b3 |  |  |
| 2020-12-12 | b1 |  |  |
| 2020-12-12 | b3 |  |  |
| 2020-12-13 | b1 |  |  |
| 2020-12-13 | b3 |  |  |
| 2020-12-14 | b1 |  |  |
| 2020-12-14 | b3 |  |  |
| 2020-12-15 | b1 |  |  |
| 2020-12-15 | b2 | Active | OOW |
| 2020-12-15 | b3 |  |  |
| 2020-12-16 | b1 |  |  |
| 2020-12-16 | b2 |  |  |
| 2020-12-16 | b3 |  |  |

This is where I am struggling.
I am facing a challenge here. I want to create new column called 'status' and if the customer data in the daily_customer_snapshot is updated in the past 5 days from the current_date
I want to set the status to be 'Active' Else 'Inactive'.
Ex:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Don't post images of data, use text. Do you require an answer that works for `mysql`, `postgresql` _and_ `tsql`? If not then remove the inappropriate tags.

Comment: Postgres or Redshift? Although they share some ancient roots, they are substantially different products.

Comment: Redshift it is @a_horse_with_no_name , Would be great if anyone could give a more optimal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you can use boolean window aggregation:

```
select 
    bds.date,
    bds.c_id,
    b.state,
    b.location,
    bool_or(b.state = 'Active') over(
        partition by bds.c_id 
        order by bds.date 
        range between interval '5 days' preceding and current row
    ) as is_active
from customer_date_series bds 
left join daily_customer_snapshot b on bds.c_id = b.c_id and bds.date = b.date 
order by 1,2;
```

This sets a boolean flag on rows where the same customer was active at least once within the last 5 days (or in the current day).

If you do want to see `'Active'`/ `'InActive'` instead (which I find less useful than a boolean) you can do:

```
    min(b.state) over(
        partition by bds.c_id 
        order by bds.date 
        range between interval '5 days' preceding and current row
    ) as status
```

... Which works because, string-wise, `'Active' < 'InActive'`.

Comment: Hi @GMB, Thanks alot for your kind help. No matter what the state (need not be only active, can be decay too)of the customer is, If we have the data entered in the snapshot in the past 5 days the customer_status is set to be 'active' else 'Inactive'. I have to have 1 entry for each date for every battery under the status column.

Comment: @SidduKattimani: so, we can do: `bool_or(b.c_id is not null) over(...)`.

Comment: But can we not create a new column 'Status' and can we set the values to 'Active' or 'Inactive' as described in the result screenshot? @GMB

Comment: @SidduKattimani: I would not recommend storing this derived information. You can compute it on the fly with the query. Or if you are going to need it on a regular basis, you can create a view.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use both tables, then a lateral join does what you want:

```
select bds.date, bds.c_id, b.state, b.location
--CASE WHEN b.state = '%ActiveDecay%' between current_date- 10 and current_date THEN 'ActIve' ELSE 'DECAY' END as STATUS
FROM battery_date_series bds LEFT JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT b.*
      FROM battery b 
      WHERE bds.c_id = b.c_id and b.date <= bds.date
      ORDER BY b.date DESC
      LIMIT 1
     ) b
     ON 1=1
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Comment: I don't want to update the state column, i would like to have a new column called 'Status', If we have the data entered for a particular c_id in the snapshot table in the past 5 days from the current date then it has to be set to 'Active' Else 'Inactive'.. Thanks for your reply though:)